# Google Colab throws error no 107 "Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using some scripts for data science on Google Colab as Google Colab+ subscriber.
I get this error every time usually after 4-5 hours have passed.
[image]
One time it worked though. The following code it combines some data to create dataset.

The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv


from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


def Dataset():
    fileCSV = open('/content/drive/My Drive/file.csv', 'w')
    csvDatawriter = csv.writer(fileCSV)

    ...

    data = []
    for m in month:
                     ...
                    #print (count,record)
                    csvDatawriter.writerow(record)
    fileCSV.close()
    print(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Dataset()
```

I also tried mounting through the file upload section.
And also added the command `drive.mount('/content/drive')`       before       `csvDatawriter.writerow(record)` but still I get that error. It's very annoying because I get it usually a`fter 4 hours have passed or more. How to solve it?